# how to Interpret the batterystats file android?

Tags: java, android, battery

Im trying  to read  the battery usage for all the applications in an android OS.

I've discovered that I can read them from batterystats file or batteryinfo, but I dont know how to interpret this file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can find dozens of answers about this topic. Check the [official document](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but how can I discover the battery used by my app?

Comment: ask a more specific question about what you exactly want to find out!

Answer (score 1):

Hope official Android documentation will help:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/setup-battery-historian

Also, Battery Historian application mentioned in the documentation can be found by the following link:
https://bathist.ef.lc/